# GAE. HTTPS redirect

Tags: php, google-app-engine

my app.yaml file has following lines:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

...

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: index.php
    secure: always
```

But, auto redirect from http to https doesn`t work.

UPD 1: Manualy entered URL with HTTPS://... works perfect

UPD 2: SSL certificate is valid

Comment: How can I check if this is development web server?

Comment: If you're connecting to local loop interface it's a dev server, if you deployed your app on GAE and you have the address <yourappname>.appspot.com then it's online

Comment: what address are you contacting?

Comment: my custom domain

Comment: So what you need is `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` http header

Comment: The Strict-Transport-Security header is ignored by the browser when your site is accessed using HTTP; this is because an attacker may intercept HTTP connections and inject the header or remove it. When your site is accessed over HTTPS with no certificate errors, the browser knows your site is HTTPS capable and will honor the  Strict-Transport-Security header.

Comment: Try this trick: `redirect_http_response_code: 301` so all HTTP requests will be redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: I just use CloudFlare (free) to do all my HTTPS redirects for AppEngine. Much simpler an no messing about with SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Comment deleted and moved to answer
This may be your issue. From GAE documentation:

> The development web server does not support HTTPS connections. It
>   ignores the secure parameter, so paths intended for use with HTTPS can
>   be tested using regular HTTP connections to the development web
>   server.

also:

> To access the versioned appspot.com URL for your application, replace
>   the periods that would usually separate the subdomain components of
>   the URL with the string "-dot-". For instance:
>   https://desired_version-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com/

Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) too

Comment: I`ve deployed my app on GAE and it is online, so it is not development

Comment: Try the appspot 'secure' version and see if works, then test on your custom domain